# How to build ios release bundle in flutter app?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods, coco

I am fresher flutter developer I don't know about how to build ios release bundle in flutter.

Any one help me how to build ios release bundle. I read many articles but I can't understand how to build.